# MySql reading from file - what is the location?

Tags: mysql, file-upload

I am trying to load the data using

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

but MySql cannot find the input file. How do I know where is it looking, or how to point it to the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [`LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html):

> The `LOCAL` keyword, if specified, is interpreted with respect to the client end of the connection:
>
> - If `LOCAL` is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started.